# Activities in library project

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

Assume that I have two apps linked to a library project that has some activities (For example LoginActivity). So I have two LoginActivity with same package name (the package name of library project) in two different apps.

At runtime I have two `com.example.lib.LoginActivity` in two different apps and If I start the `LoginActivity` through Intent, which activity will start?

Comment: Its Depends on your importing statement

Comment: You should post a code example.

Comment: it depends on how you create a starting Intent and your manifest file

Comment: do you mean starting `com.example.lib.LoginActivity` from a 3rd app?

Comment: I guess it should create intent chooser with the both apps name!

Comment: how do you start your Activity,  what is an Intent?

Comment: Example: `startActivity(new Intent("com.example.lib", "com.example.lib.LoginActivity")`

Comment: so you want to start it in the application whose package name is "com.example.lib" you cannot have two or more apps with the same package name